# I am assigning three variables at a same time but code is throwing me an error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

my code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using  namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {6,7,3,61,9};
    int *p = arr;
    int a,b,c = *p, *(p+1), *(p+2);
    // int a,b,c ;
    // a = *p;
    // b = *(p+1);
    // c = *(p+2);
    return 0;
}
```

---

this is throwing me an error: "error: expected ')' before '+' token".
When I tried to run the commented code then there was no error.
Can anyone please explain why there is an error.

Comment: "Can anyone please explain why there is an error." Because the language standard does not allow you to write code like that for the purpose you have in mind. I'm not sure how you expect the question to be answered, really. The language is what it is. If you want to know "how can I initialize multiple variables on the same line?", then you should *ask that instead*.

Comment: `auto [a,b,c] = std::make_tuple(*p, *(p+1), *(p+2));`

Comment: `int a,b,c = *p, *(p+1), *(p+2);` : this is similar to how you would initialize several variables in Lua: `local a,b,c = 42, "Hello", "world!"`. But C++ has a different syntax...

Comment: `std::tie` is what you forgot.

Answer (score 6):

That's not the correct syntax for declaring and initializing multiple variables in C++. If you really want to have them all be on one line, it would be

```
int a = *p, b = *(p + 1), c = *(p + 2);
```

But a lot of people will recommend just having three separate lines:

```
int a = *p;
int b = *(p + 1);
int c = *(p + 2);
```

Comment: _But a lot of people will recommend just having three separate lines_ Absolutely, count me in.